# OData V4: Is it possible to only select fields from a parent entity (i.e. navigation property)?

Tags: select, odata, expand, odata-v4

In *OData V3*, I can select just fields from parent/ancestor entities like this:
http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Order_Details(OrderID=10248,ProductID=11)?&$select=Product/Category/CategoryName&$expand=Product/Category

That query returns only *CategoryName*, it does not include any fields from *Order_Details* or *Product*.  This behavior is very important to our application for performance reasons.  Selecting all fields when we don't need them can have a significant impact on query performance.

There does not seem to be a way to accomplish the same in OData V4.  The equivalent query returns all fields from *Order_Details* and *Product*
http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Order_Details(OrderID=10248,ProductID=11)?$expand=Product($expand=Category($select=CategoryName))

The closest I can get is to just select one field from each level, introduces a lot of complexity into our code, and it has been difficult to ensure that all queries (future and existing) adhere to this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The closest I can get is to just select one field from each level,
> introduces a lot of complexity into our code, and it has been
> difficult to ensure that all queries (future and existing) adhere to
> this rule.

Looks something like this:

http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Order_Details(OrderID=10248,ProductID=11)?$expand=Product($select=Category;$expand=Category($select=CategoryName))&$select=Product

There is certainly a bit of added complexity here, but this was acceptable in my case.

Comment: Brilliant!  I guess I mistakenly thought a Select could not be used on a parent relationship field.  Perhaps this didn't work back in 2018 but more likely I just overlooked this option.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for this is:

https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Order_Details(OrderID=10248,ProductID=11)/Product/Category?$select=CategoryName

results in:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata#Categories(CategoryName)/$entity",
    "CategoryName": "Dairy Products"
}
```

The key OData v4 concept here is that the *path*, that is everything before the `?` defines the *resource* that is being served, and by that the *shape* of the resulting graph. The output of `$select` and `$expand` (*projections*) is constrained to match the requested resource.

- So in v3 with $select you could return a more arbitrary structure but in v4 the `$select` and `$expand` can only *mask* the graph by returning what is essentially a subset of `$select=*&$expand=*`.

To get around this but still allow similar query scenarios in v4 we can *compose* an entity path expression to *any resource within the parent path.
So we move the *resource selector path* from the v3 `$select` `Product/Cateogry' and append it the path of our resource` ~/Order_Details(OrderID=10248,ProductID=11)`

> **NOTE:** There is a strong caveat to this, whilst the OData specification  describes this behaviour, not all implementations support deep resource selections like this. The specification is a guidance document on the *standard* protocol, not all implemenations are 100% compliant.

A simplification of this is to try selecting just the `Product` from the same query, notice here we do not use any *query parameters* at all:

[~/Order_Details(OrderID=10248,ProductID=11)/Product](https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Order_Details(OrderID=10248,ProductID=11)/Product)

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata#Products/$entity",
    "ProductID": 11,
    "ProductName": "Queso Cabrales",
    "SupplierID": 5,
    "CategoryID": 4,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "1 kg pkg.",
    "UnitPrice": 21.0000,
    "UnitsInStock": 22,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 30,
    "ReorderLevel": 30,
    "Discontinued": false
}
```

> You can see in this response that the **context** or the *resource* that is being returned is a `$metadata#Products/$entity` and not an `Order_Details/$entity`

Once your resource is selected, normal v4 `$select` and `$expand` logic is evaluated. This is documented in the specification under [4.3 Addressing Entities](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc371341732)

> These rules are recursive, so it is possible to address a single entity via another single entity, a collection via a single entity and even a collection via a collection; examples include, but are not limited to:
>
> - By following a navigation from a single entity to another related entity (see rule: entityNavigationProperty)
>   Example 14:
>   `http://host/service/Products(1)/Supplier`

#### Update:

I've substantially edited this post from my original answer, at the time i misinterpreted OP's request and the structure they were expecting, but this is still relevant information in 2022 and none of the answers directly produces the desired behaviour.

Comment: This is a possible workaround and helps in this contrived example, but doesn't help for my actual queries where I'm using filters and don't have the ID for the entity.  What I need is capability that OData V3 had.  The answer is helpful, though, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SeanJ_2173 in that case you select from the child table, with a filter that matches the parent. I didn't offer that in the solution because your question was specifically for an Item query not a collection query. :) you should have posted with an example that was closer to your actual queries.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solutions would be to create View with required schema on your db server and try to fetch data from this datasource with filters and column name(s) instead.

Especially when facing issues with performance.

The best way would be to register this class to your IoC as singleton

```
public class InternalODataEdmModelBuilder
{
    private readonly ODataConventionModelBuilder _oDataConventionModelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    private IEdmModel _edmModel;

    public InternalODataEdmModelBuilder()
    {
        ODataEntitySetsConfigInternal.Register(_oDataConventionModelBuilder);
    }

    // cache
    public IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        return _edmModel ?? (_edmModel = _oDataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}

internal static class ODataEntitySetsConfigInternal
{
    public static void Register(ODataConventionModelBuilder oDataModelBuilder)
    {
        if (oDataModelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("'ODataConventionModelBuilderWebApi' cannot be null");
        }

        oDataModelBuilder.EntitySet<YourView>("YourView").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.YourKey);
    }
}
```

And then inject this registered object in your API controller and build your query from URL like this:

```
        ODataQueryContext queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(_oDataConventionModel, typeof(YourViewEFType), null);
        var option = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, Request);
        var data = option.ApplyTo(data, new ODataQuerySettings { EnsureStableOrdering = false });
```

And then map data into your POCO (API EDM model shown to the public world).

Hope this helps.

Comment: A viable option; however, we must keep our data model normal based on all the ways we dynamically extend our data layer.